# php - multidimensional array (keep index array)

Tags: php, arrays

I have array like this:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
     0 => array:1 [▼
        "2018-06-13" => "hadir"
       ]
     1 => array:1 [▼
        "2018-06-12" => "hadir"
       ]
     2 => array:1 [▼
        "2018-06-11" => "alfa"
       ]
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
     0 => array:1 [▼
        "2018-06-13" => "hadir"
       ]
     1 => array:1 [▼
        "2018-06-12" => "hadir"
       ]
     2 => array:1 [▼
        "2018-06-11" => "hadir"
       ]
  ]
]
```

But I want convert this array to:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
       "2018-06-13" => "hadir"

       "2018-06-12" => "hadir"

       "2018-06-11" => "alfa"

  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
      "2018-06-13" => "hadir"

      "2018-06-12" => "hadir"

      "2018-06-11" => "hadir"
  ]
]
```

I have tried my own solutions using things like `array_merge`, `array_walk_recursive`, and `RecursiveIteratorIterator` with `RecursiveArrayIterator`. But in my practice it doesn't work.

Help Me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard part was re-creating the original array :)

Loop through the top level array with a counter
Each element of that array is an indexed array. Loop through each of htem with a counter.
Each of those elements is an associative array containing the data you want to use as keys/values in the new array.  Pop through each of those wtih a `foreach` and build the new array, top level being indexed on `$i` and each of those elements containing your associative array.

```
<?php

$arr[0][]=array('2018-06-13'=>"hadir");
$arr[0][]=array('2018-06-12'=>"hadir");
$arr[0][]=array('2018-06-11'=>"alfa");
$arr[1][]=array('2018-06-13'=>"hadir");
$arr[1][]=array('2018-06-12'=>"hadir");
$arr[1][]=array('2018-06-11'=>"hadir");

print_r($arr);

for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++){
    for($j=0;$j<count($arr[$i]);$j++){
        foreach($arr[$i][$j] as $k=>$v){
            $newarr[$i][$k]=$v;
        }
    }
}

print_r($newarr);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of clean/direct approaches using the splat operator (`...`).  Both effectively "shift the deepest subarrays up a level" by merging the individual subarrays.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/3jNft))  *use one approach or the other depending on style preference

```
$array = [
    [
        ['2018-06-13' => "hadir"],
        ['2018-06-12' => "hadir"],
        ['2018-06-11' => "alfa"]
    ],
    [
        ['2018-06-13' => "hadir"],
        ['2018-06-12' => "hadir"],
        ['2018-06-11' => "hadir"]
    ]
];

var_export(
    array_reduce(
        $array,
        function ($carry, $item) {
            $carry[] = array_merge(...$item);
            return $carry;
        },
        []
    )
);

echo "\n---\n";

foreach ($array as &$sub1) {  // modify by reference
    $sub1 = array_merge(...$sub1);
}
var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    '2018-06-13' => 'hadir',
    '2018-06-12' => 'hadir',
    '2018-06-11' => 'alfa',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    '2018-06-13' => 'hadir',
    '2018-06-12' => 'hadir',
    '2018-06-11' => 'hadir',
  ),
)
---
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    '2018-06-13' => 'hadir',
    '2018-06-12' => 'hadir',
    '2018-06-11' => 'alfa',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    '2018-06-13' => 'hadir',
    '2018-06-12' => 'hadir',
    '2018-06-11' => 'hadir',
  ),
)
```